# VBA: Automatically saving the excel sheet as V-1, V-2 and V-3 depending on if there is a file with that name already in the folder

Tags: excel, vba

I am working in VBA. I want to save the excel document with values from my sheet. However, repeats of the same file name can exist. If the same file name is repeated, I would like the VBA to save it as a different version number. For example, if the file name is CAT DOG and there is a second file saved as CAT DOG, I want the VBA to automatically save it as V-2. And if there is already a V-2, to than save if as V-3 and so on. This is the code I have so far. It saves great normally but I am having trouble with getting the version numbers added. I have attached an image of the code so far

''''

```
path = ""
filename1 = ws.Range("D5").Text & 
ws.Range("O3").Text`e`ws.Range("D6").Text
If filename1(path & filename1 & ".xlsm") = False Then
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=(path & filename1 & ".xlsm"), 
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
Exit Sub
End If


Do While Saved = False
 If filename1(path & filename1 & x & ".xlsm") = False Then
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=(path & filename1 & x & ".xlsm"), 
 FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
  Saved = True
 Else
   x = x + 1
 End If
Loop
 MsgBox "New file version saved (version " & x & ")"
```

Comment: Might be easier to loop through your sheet first and append Vs to each cell then you won't run into any duplicates when saving?

Comment: Where is the rest of your subroutine? I don't understand how you're using `filename1` as a string, but then it's almost like you're using it as a function `filename1(...) = False` - how does `path` even work here when you set it to an empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Do Not Overwrite Saved Files (Versioning)

- Adjust the values in the constants section.
- Using the current setup, it will create files with the following names:

  ```
  CAT DOG.xlsm
  CAT DOG (V-2).xlsm
  CAT DOG (V-3).xlsm
  etc.
  ```

  in the `Test` folder on drive `C`.

**The Code**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DoNotOverWrite()
    
    Const dFolderPath As String = "C:\Test\"
    Const dBaseName As String = "CAT DOG"
    Const dLeft As String = " (V-"
    Const dFirstNumber As Long = 2
    Const dRight As String = ")"
    Const dExtension As String = ".xlsm"
    
    Dim dFilePath As String: dFilePath = dFolderPath & dBaseName & dExtension
    Dim dFileName As String: dFileName = Dir(dFilePath)
    Dim n As Long: n = dFirstNumber - 1
     
    Do Until Len(dFileName) = 0
        n = n + 1
        dFilePath = dFolderPath & dBaseName & dLeft & n & dRight & dExtension
        dFileName = Dir(dFilePath)
    Loop
    
    ' If the workbook is the one containing this code, use 'ThisWorkbook'.
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs dFilePath, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    
    If n < dFirstNumber Then
        MsgBox "File saved.", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "New file version saved (version " & n & ")", vbInformation
    End If

End Sub
```